# What are the differences between font-feature-settings vs font-variant in css fonts settings

Tags: css, fonts

What is the difference between `font-feature-settings` and `font-variant` in css fonts?

Does anybody know?  Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: I think that can easily be found by Googling. Have you looked at these two pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings ? The latter says "This property is a low-level feature designed to handle special cases where no other way to enable or access an OpenType font feature exists" and "Whenever possible, Web authors should use the font-variant shorthand property".

Answer (score 2):

Look at these two CSS rules, 
both these rules does the same thing,

```
font-feature-settings: "smcp" on;
font-variant: small-caps;
```

but since font-feature-settings is reserved for more specialized operations which can't be achieved by any other manner you should stick to font-variant when there arrives an option to choose between them. 
Don't kill a fly with Bazooka.

In this case CSS tricks will be more helpful for you,

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-variant/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/

and this too
https://webkit.org/blog/5735/css-font-features/

Comment: what are these specialized operations that the font-variant can not do?

Comment: @OneLearner here's the demo of things font-feature-settings can do http://open-type.surge.sh/ 
you'll surely find a similar list for font-variant